# How to know which View is accessing the ViewModel Silverlight MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I am working on a Silverlight application with MVVM pattern. Although it is not advised to use one viewmodel for more than one views, but in my case I had to do it for code reusability. Anyways, the constructor of the viewmodel does some data access which is only supposed to be done for a specific view and not the rest. **Is there a way in the ViewModel constructor that I could see which View has requested this instance of ViewModel?**

Comment: It depends on how you instantiate your view models, but in general, no there isn't... the view models shouldn't know anything about the views. Follow the pattern properly and your problems will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Inject an interface to the view model's constructor which will contain the information needed. Implement the interface in the views. Whichever class is constructing the view model and views needs to pass a view instance to the view model. If you are using a DI container you'll have to create some sort of a wrapper which will know how to properly create the view model and inject views into it.

It's not a terribly wrong design, sometimes it's the only way to do things in MVVM. Just do it properly and you'll be fine.

Comment: It **is** a terribly wrong design. He said he only wanted to reuse code and therefore uses the same vm type twice, so the correct approach would be to extract the reusable part into its own type and use composition.

Comment: @Martin: Read the question in bold

Answer (score 0):

Your last statement (i.e. the one highlighted) suggests you're not doing proper MVVM...views should be instantiated in response to the creation of a view model, not the other way round. I also find it difficult to envisage a case where mapping multiple views to a view model would be advantageous, let alone actually needed...why can't you just use data triggers to set a single view's template?

To answer your question though it is actually possible to do. If your view model is being created first then give it a command handler and give your view an interaction trigger that calls the command in response to it's "Loaded" event, along with an appropriate CommandParameter identifying the view.

If, on the other hand, you're creating the view first and binding the DataContext via a locator then you'll need to bind via an ObjectDataProvider so that you can call a method and pass in your view's identifying data:

```
<vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True"  />

<ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource Locator}" MethodName="GetViewModel" x:Key="MyProvider">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <system:String>My parameter</system:String>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Your view's DataContext binding will now look like this:

```
DataContext="{StaticResource MyProvider}"
```

And of course you'll need to add the function to the locator:

```
public MyViewModel GetViewModel(string id)
{
    // create an instance of MyViewModel here, passing id into the constructor
}
```

While these technically answer your question I have to stress that they are both horrible hacks that you really shouldn't need to do if you're adhering to the MVVM pattern properly.